# Big-O/Little-o with high probability (in the context of random graphs)

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, random-graphs

I'm getting in a muddle trying to understand statements which include both Landau symbols and the notion of "with high probability" (w.h.p.) in random graphs.

**Setting/Background**

Reading about Erdos-Renyi random graphs, I come across statements like

(1) "with high probability, the largest component $C_1$ has size $O(\log(n))$

and, in a separate situation,

(2) "with high probability $\text{diam}(G) = (3 + o(1))(1/\varepsilon)\log(\varepsilon^3n)$"

In the context of Erdos-Renyi random graphs, I understand "$G(n,p)$ has property A w.h.p." to mean that $\mathbb{P}(G\text{ has A}) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$

Furthermore, I understand $f(n) = O(g(n))$ (in a more general setting) to mean that there are constants $n_0$ and $M$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$, $|f(n)|\leq M.|g(n)|$.

Finally, I understand $f(n) = o(g(n)))$ to mean $|f(n)/g(n)|\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

**Question**

The only sensible way I can think of to parse statement (1) is as follows:

(1') There exists constant $M$ such that $\mathbb{P}(|C_1| \leq M\log(n)) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$

Is this correct?

On the other hand, the best I can come up with for (2) is

(2') $$\mathbb{P}\left(\left| \frac{\text{diam}(G)\varepsilon}{\log(\varepsilon^3 n)}-3 \right| \to 0 \right)=1$$

which I'm significantly less convinced by. This is based on the idea that perhaps

$$f(G(n,p)) = o(g(n)) \text{ w.h.p.}$$

should be interpreted to mean $$\mathbb{P}\left(\left| \frac{f(G(n,p))}{g(n)} \right| \to 0 \right)=1$$

(NB: As this is my first question on here, please feel free to give pointers on how I can better match community expectations for questions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation of (1) is spot on.  An intuitive way to think of it is that there is a constant $M$ so that the probability of any connected component having more than $M\log(n)$ vertices is essentially zero (probability getting ever closer to zero as the size of the graph, $n$, increases).

For (2), think of $o(1)$ as a vanishing function (i.e. some $f(n)\to 0$).  Thus, saying w.h.p $\text{diam}(G)=(3+o(1))(1/\epsilon)\log(\epsilon^{2}n)$ just means that as $n\to\infty$, w.h.p $\text{diam}(G)\sim \frac{3}{\epsilon}\log(\epsilon^{2}n)$; in other words, the diameter of $G$ (w.h.p) is asymptotic to $\frac{3}{\epsilon}\log(\epsilon^{2}n)$.  What the $(3+o(1))$ tells you is that the constant out front is typically larger than $3$ (but negligibly larger).  This is stronger than saying $\text{diam}(G)=\Theta(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\log(\epsilon^{2}n))$ because you can explicitly say what the best constant is (i.e. the $3$).

Comment: Thanks @Travis for this. The situation with o(1) is now much clearer, but I'm still struggling to understand how w.h.p. interacts with it. Two things go to infinity here: (a) property A of G(n,p) occurs w.h.p. if P(A) tends to 1 as n goes to infinity; (b) diam(G)=(3+o(1)).g(n) (with no reference to "w.h.p.") if diam(G)~3.g(n) as n goes to infinity. Combining the two I'm left trying to claim that P[diam(G)~3.g(n) as n->infinity]->1 as n->infinity which doesn't make a whole lot of sense. (Trying to correct this is how I ended up with interpretation (2'))

Comment: @OnyGo, it helps to think about the things like $o(1)$ as a specific function that is too messy to write down.  For example, perhaps $o(1)$ refers to a function like $\frac{1}{n\log(n)}$, so perhaps, the diameter is actually something like $(3+\frac{1}{n\log(n)})(1/\epsilon)\log(\epsilon^{2}n)$.  Once you have a specific function, you can compute the probability that this is actually the diameter.  Perhaps the probability is $1-o(1)$ where this time the $o(1)$ is "shorthand" for something like $\frac{1}{n}$.  Because the probability converges to 1 you can say w.h.p.

Comment: @OnyGo, By too messy to write down, I just mean that it is un-necessarily cumbersome.  People choose to write $o(1)$ instead of some messy function so that it's easier to read and still captures the essential part.

Comment: This additional comment about thinking about the o(1) as a specific function is exactly the extra push I needed to get my head round this. Thanks for your help!